# Background Check and 2 week notice for Federal Government Job

Tags: resignation, human-resources, notice-period, background-check, government

Person got a tenative offer for a Government job and the job and HR has been so nice to the person. They are short staffed so they put in a two week notice because the class was in another state and they only had two weeks to pick up their family and find a place and move and find childcare before class started and they did not want to leave the nice people stranded even though I told them say nothing. The old job was appreciative of that at the time. Their last date is coming soon and the background check is not over, they have found a place and childcare they notified HR from the new job that the date is coming soon and was told if the background check is not over by their last day that they will move the start date and not to resign from the job, but now their place of work wants them gone and is holding to the last date they posted in the two week notice. What happens now, they have signed a lease in a new place in another state. Somebody help me help them. If their last day comes before their background check is not finished does that mean they will not continue with the hiring? Thank you so much.

Comment: "If their last day comes before their background check is not finished does that mean they will not continue with the hiring?" Who the hell knows! But that kind of last-minute suggestion doesn't bode well for them. I've worked for a Federal Agency and delays of several months were definitely possible.

Answer (score 2):

> What happens now ?

They will finish their notice period and than they are unemployed until the background check finishes. If it's clear, they can start the new job. If it fails they need to look for a new job. They should start looking now!!

> If their last day comes before their background check is not finished does that mean they will not continue with the hiring?

No. The new company generally doesn't care what happens at the old company as long a you can show up on your start date.

If your friend has a clean background and don't expect any trouble from the background check, they just have to wait it out. Move to the new apartment put the kids in childcare, safe as much money as you can, and hope for the best. Start job searching right away as a safety measure.